# Flutter : How to Convert DateTime to TimeOfDay?

Tags: flutter

I have this code of time picker, then I  want to set the initial Time from a DateTime variable:

```
Future<Null> _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
final TimeOfDay pickedS = await showTimePicker(
    context: context,
    initialTime: createdAt,
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
       return MediaQuery(
         data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: false),
        child: child,
      );});

if (pickedS != null && pickedS != selectedTime )
  setState(() {
    selectedTime = pickedS;
    myTweets[actualTweetIndex].createdAt = dateFormat.format(selectedDate.toLocal()) +' ${selectedTime.hour}:${selectedTime.minute}:00 +0000 '+ selectedDate.year.toString();
  });
```

}

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `TimeOfDay` class have a dedicated constructor for that :

```
TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime time)
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TimeOfDay-class.html)